# Inheritance and instance variable in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I know that instance variables have nothing to do with inheritance:

```
class A

  def initialize
    @x = 2
  end

end

class B < A

  def puts_x
    puts @x
   end

  def x=(value)
    @x = value
  end

end

b = B.new
b.puts_x
b.x=3
b.puts_x
```

This outputs:

```
2
3
```

Here, class `B` inherits from class `A`, and `@x` in class `B` has nothing to do with inheritance.

But the output is `2`. I want to understand it.

The "[Ruby Inheritance](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_inheritance.html)" page says:

> Since instance variables have nothing to do with inheritance, it
>   follows that an instance variable used by a subclass cannot "shadow"
>   an instance variable in the super-class. If a subclass uses an
>   instance variable with the same name as a variable used by one of its
>   ancestors, it will overwrite the value of its ancestor's variable.

I also want any examples for this.

Comment: In class `B`, you created a setter method `x=(value)`, and since you already inherited the `initialize` method from class `A` and initially set your instance variable `@x = 2`, when you called `b.x = 3`, you called your setter method to change the value of that instance variable. So now `@x = 3` from there on for that instance of `b`

Comment: *"It is said that ..."* - please include a source.

Comment: You can refer to http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_inheritance.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`B` inherits `initialize` from `A`.

At object creation, `initialize` is invoked. So you get `@x` set to `2` even for objects of class `B`.

I think, the sentences you are quoting refer to this scenario:

```
class A
  def initialize
    @x = 42
  end
end

class B < A
  def initialize
    @x = 23
  end
end

h = B.new
```

Now, `h` has just one instance variable `@x` with value `23`. It is not like there is one `@x` from `B` and one from `A`. You can see this here:

```
class A
  def initialize
    @x = 42
  end

  def set_x_from_a
    @x = 12
  end

  def print_x_from_a
    puts @x
  end
end

class B < A
  def initialize
    @x = 23
  end

  def set_x_from_b
    @x = 9
  end

  def print_x_from_b
    puts @x
  end
end

h = B.new
h.print_x_from_a            # => 23
h.print_x_from_b            # => 23
h.set_x_from_a
h.print_x_from_b            # => 12
h.set_x_from_b
h.print_x_from_a            # => 9
```

Comment: Thanx for your reply. your explanation is not that subclass change its ancestor's value.I think that superclass change its subclass's value.You can refer to http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_inheritance.html

Comment: @Messi: You are right. But still ... there is just one `@x` existing in the **object** no matter which classes method you are accessing it from.

Comment: But `h` is still the instance of subclass and `@x` is instance variable of the subclass.The book says that changing the value of the instance variable of the subclass overwrites  superclass's value.Where is instance variable of the superclass in your explanation?

Comment: @Messi: The point is, there is no instance variable in the superclass. The instance variable exists in the instance, in `h` (hence the name). There is just one.

Comment: So if  there is no instance variable in the superclass, how does subclass change superclass's value?

Comment: In your explanation,where can I find that subclass overwrites superclass's value?

Comment: You cannot find it there. There is no instance variable in the superclass. Nor in the subclass. The explanation in your book is sloppy.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations,I understand now.Thanks again.